# Best software installation kit for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, installation, package

I want to create an installer for my software and I want something much better than the typical software installers (like you get with Package Maker or White Box Packages).  I want to be able to do full screen with full layouts and such.

What's the best development kit/tools to create a rich and powerful software installer?

Comment: My recommendation: don't. Just use PackageMaker (or some other way of creating standard .pkg installers); my experience is that the alternatives wind up creating more problems than they solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be rich, but it is not the OS X "style" - I have not seen any installer do that in ages.

If you would like to do a tutorial or orientation, I would launch that after the installation business has been completed.

BTW, full screen etc are also discouraged on Windows.